# "A duplicate insert block exists for class xx in the source files"

Tags: visual-studio, evc4

In `Embedded Visual Studio 4`, I'm attempting to add a `class` though the `class wizard.` 
Since, the file existed already, the first attempt failed. So I deleted the file and attempted to add the class again.

Now I get the error message

```
"A duplicate insert block exists for class xx in the source files"
```

and I can't figure out what to do about it, apart from roll back my code.

Has anyone seen this, if so, would you know how to fix it?

Comment: What language/platform are you talking about? We need more context.

Comment: Instead of useless tags like "adding", how about using tags that actually describe what technology you were using.  Is this from an IDE?  Which one?

Comment: I've added the requested info.. Pls take away the neg vote.

Comment: You're using 3 separate tags, none of which have been used before.  How about using the same tags as other people?

Comment: Apart from adding classwizard I'm not sure I can see which ones I could use. I mean you asked me to use tags that describe the tech and I did. I'm adding a class in evc4.

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that you have duplicate blocks, not duplicate entries. Perhaps you renamed a block by mistake.

e.g. say in AFX block,

Check that you have only one of each of these in MyClass.h:

```
//{{AFX_DATA(CMyClass)
//{{AFX_VIRTUAL(CMyClass)
//{{AFX_MSG(CMyClass)
```

...and that you have only one of each of these in MyClass.cpp:

```
//{{AFX_DATA_INIT(CMyClass)
//{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CMyClass)
//{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyClass)
```